# Qt5 dynamic translation issues for C++ defined properties

Tags: qt, qml, translation

I am currently working on somebody else code and I need to fix a bug linked with dynamic translation.

When the language is changed, the Loader is reloaded, it works but it generates unwanted effects (including the bug mentioned above).

So I tried to look for a way to dynamically change the translation without reloading everything.

I added `m_engine->retranslate()` in my `switchLanguage` function and this works perfectly, but only for texts directly defined in QML files. The thing is there is also a lot of text defined with `setContextProperty` in the C++ main controller class, and for them, it doesn't work at all (which seems pretty normal since m_engine is a `QQmlApplicationEngine`).

I don't see how I can simply force these texts to retranslate too. I have them in pretty much every controller function and they are used by different QML files. I am afraid that there will be no other choice but to change completely the way translation is managed. I hope advanced programmers can help me with this.

Other information:

- I work with 5.13.0 version of Qt.
- I don't use Designer and cannot use `ui.retranslateUi()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell how your main controller class looks like, so here is a short general answer.

You can install an `eventFilter` and listen for `LanguageChange`.

In constructor of "main controller class", add this:

```
auto *core = QCoreApplication::instance();
if(core != nullptr)
{
    core->installEventFilter(this);
}
```

Then add a function to your class:

```
bool MainControllerClass::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(watched);
    if(event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
    {
         //set properties again or emit property changed signals
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already saw solutions using *QEvent::LanguageChange* but I have a lot of properties and I didn't want to reset all properties, even the ones I don't need in the current view, everytime the language is changed. It would be a little too much knowing I only use 1 or 2 properties per view.

Comment: If you write your getters as `return tr(the_string)` you can already reduce the maintenance and only need to emit for each property, or stuff everything in one extra layer which you can then emit has changed (making it only one single emit). IMHO best would be to not use strings from C++, but where it makes sense use enums, and otherwise vaule type properties (except string of course). But I warn you, if you don't take translation into account from the start of the project, you are going to spend a lot of effort at one point....

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am well aware that the design of the app is not optimun but I arrived on the project after it was in production.